# How to get rid of some characters from a field of string in Hive?

Tags: hiveql

I want to get rid of some characters in a field which are stting format. For example, replace the punctuation as blank character. How to realize it given the candidate characters to erase.

Comment: Add a data sample + required results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace` with pattern for example `'[_.,!?-]'`, list characters you want to get rid in the pattern. This will replace character in the pattern with spaces:

```
select regexp_replace('test_string_with-puctuations,.!?','[_.,!?-]',' ');
```

Output:

```
test string with puctuations
```

Comment: select regexp_replace('test_string；’。、《_with-827puctuations,234.!?',   
'[_.,!?-]:;|\{}()*&^%$#@!~`<>/‘’=，。、《》？；：“”】【！@#￥%……&*（）——+~·',   ' ');

Comment: Why this query can not get rid of the puctuations from the string

Comment: 1. Semicolon ; should be escaped in hive because it has special meaning. Also if you want to remove all non-ascii then you can use `\\P{ASCII}` template. `select regexp_replace('test_string\\;’??«with-827puctuations,234.!?', '\\P{ASCII}|[.,!?-]|\\;', ' ');`

Comment: @yanachen  '\\P{ASCII}|[.,!?-]|\\;' means non-ascii character or any of `.,!?-` or semicolon